# where is file entry.S in v2.6.39.4?

Tags: linux, version, system-calls

I am studying system call in linux with source code in version 2.6.39.4. 
Books said that system call is implementd in entry.S, located in arch/i386/kernel/entry.S,
but I can't find that file in v2.6.39.4. 
so which file implement system call in my version? Any difference with old ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information in your books seems to be outdated.

You should find what you're looking for in `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S` and `arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S`.